# When I run "redis-server --service-start" I get error code 1056 "Start service failed: unknown error"

Tags: redis

I can't find any explanation online for this error or any fix. Does anyone have any ideas? The exact result is:

```
HandleServiceCommands: system error caught. error code=1056, message = StartService failed: unknown error
```

Answer (score 0):

Restart it

```
redis-server --service-stop
redis-server --service-start
```